# Is it possible to upload files directly in a specific Google Drive?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have a client that needs a file upload form on their site, and they want the files to be uploaded directly to their Google Drive. I want to know if it is possible to do or if I am fooling myself with this. I have already searched a little on the internet and also tested some things, but everything I run into just let me select a file from the visitor's Drive and it requires an authentication to proceed (obviously).

What I want to do is put a file upload form which will upload the file to my PHP script, and then, the PHP script will put the given file in my client's Drive. Is this possible in any way? And if so, could you point me in the good direction? If it is not possible, I will simply suggest another solution to my client.

I have already downloaded the Google Drive SDK and looked a little though it, so there's no need to start from the beginning with me.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Hi Jonathan,

You have to use google api surly you can upload files directly to drive
you can refer below link:
[google drive api ][1]


  [1]: http://hublog.hubmed.org/archives/001954.html
```

and you can also get working example from https://github.com/eduardocasas/Google-Drive-PHP-API-Simple-App-Example